# what does the structure "but of.." mean here and in general?

Tags: grammar

I couldnt understand what "but of" means in this lyrics:
"I'm over the rainbows
But of Medusa kiss me and crucify"

could you help me understand?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

It's

> ...I'm over the rainbows
>
> But oh Medusa kiss me and crucify

*oh* in place of *of* ([Source](https://play.google.com/music/preview/Tvxwihyrapnns52ksm5d3iuhhu4)), where Medusa is a [reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medusa) to a female monster that turns onlookers to stone

Comment: okay thank you, somewhere I saw the lyrics were entered as "of" instead of "oh"